# VBA/VSTO Excel: Test on cell identity

Tags: vba, excel, vsto

This question is somewhat related to this one: [VBA: What happens to Range objects if user deletes cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127311/vba-what-happens-to-range-objects-if-user-deletes-cells)

Is there any way to reliably test for identity of two cell references, and, more importantly, to store cell references over time?

Consider the following example:

```
Sub TestCellIdentity ()

   Dim r As Range
   Set r = Application.ActiveCell
   r.Value = "Some Value"

   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Set ws = r.Worksheet

   Dim n As String
   n = ws.Name

   Dim c As Range
   Set c = Worksheets (n).Cells (r.Row, r.Column)

   MsgBox ("ActiveCell ptr: " & CStr (ObjPtr (r)) & "Value: " & r.Value _
     & "; Indirect access ptr: " & CStr (ObjPtr (c)) & " Value: " & c.Value)
End Sub
```

Running the example shows that ObjPtr (r) and ObjPtr (c) are different, even though they refer to the same cell. What is worse, it seems to me (from some tests) that I cannot assume that two cell objects (object references) with the same ObjPtr reference are guaranteed to refer to the same cell (i.e. I cannot store the ObjPtr value and use it, e.g., as a key somewhere).

Hence my question: How can I uniquely identify a cell in Excel in a way that survives renaming, cutting, and/or pasting cells in the Worksheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pointer is created each time a variable is assigned hence you get different references unless you assign one variable to another in which case it is the same pointer and has the same reference. Unless you use a Static declaration the reference will usually change each time you run the sub procedure. If you declare the pointer as Static and assign it once it should maintain a constant reference each time the code is run even if a user moves the cell. I ran this code to test it and it seems to work.

```
    Sub TestCellIdentityModified()

    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Static rngStatic As Range

    ' assign cell to pointer
    Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 4)
    Debug.Print "rng1 = " & ObjPtr(rng1)

    ' assign same cell to a different pointer
    Set rng2 = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 4)
    Debug.Print "rng2 = " & ObjPtr(rng2); ""

    ' assign one pointer to another
    Set rng2 = rng1
    Debug.Print "rng2 reassigned as rng1 pointer = " & ObjPtr(rng2)

    ' one time assignment of the same cell to a static pointer
    If rngStatic Is Nothing Then Set rngStatic = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 4)
    Debug.Print "rngStatic = " & ObjPtr(rngStatic)

    Debug.Print " "

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard way would be assign it a [Defined Name](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DefinedNames.aspx).

(You asked for a way that survives renaming, but I'm not sure if you just mean the name of the worksheet.)

Comment: And to make it more foolproof, you can hide defined names, so that they can only be "seen" by VBA or tools like Jan Karel Pieterse's Name Manager.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I didn't know about hidden names.