# How to check if a range exists in Excel using C#/VSTO

Tags: excel, vsto, range, exists

I'm currently working on a C# project using VSTO and Excel.
The fact is that I'm saving Ranges in my program, but when I delete this range on Excel, it give me an error in the program. And i don't find a way to check if the cell still exist or not.

Do you know a way to check if the range exist or not?

Comment: Can you post some code and point out the lines where you are getting errors?

Comment: I'm just checking using Application.Intersect with the deleted range and another one to check if it's the one I'm looking for. And it give me the error with "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC". So it just tell that the range doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12127311/293078 has an interesting discussion (with a fabulous answer :)

Comment: thank Doug,
I hoped I can check without catch an error but it's seem not possible.