# Empty Excel range collection possible?

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to have an empty Excel range collection, i.e. can it happen to have an object obj of type Excel.Range such that

```
obj.Cells.Count = 0
```

I have the strong feeling that this is not possible.

Please give an authoritative references that it is indeed impossible, or provide a counter example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349613/what-does-the-keyword-set-actually-do-in-vba) will partially answer your question. 
All I can say on top of that is that all objects have to be `Set` in order to call any type of methods on them. It's the basics of the [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) concept. You can have an object of any type for example 
`Dim obj as Range`
`Dim obj as Application`
`Dim obj as Long`
but it really is just a reserved room in the memory for this variable and is waiting to have a reference assigned. 
So simply the answer is: No, it is not possible to have an empty range object set. 
Check it out yourself:

```
Sub RangeTest()
    Dim rng As Range
    'Set rng = Range("A1")
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="rngName", RefersTo:=rng.Address
    MsgBox "count: " & rng.Cells.Count
End Sub
```

obviously the above fails, however »

```
Sub RangeTest()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1")
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="rngName", RefersTo:=rng.Address
    MsgBox "count: " & rng.Cells.Count
End Sub
```

---

also 
[Developer’s Guide to the Excel 2010 Range Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg192736(v=office.14).aspx) clearly states

> The Range object represents one or more cells, and can be used to
>   represent a single cell, a row, a column, a selection of cells that
>   contain one or more contiguous blocks of cells, or a 3-D range.

Comment: The question asks for an object of type Range, as such the variable must be assigned, not just declared. However, the reference you supplied in the last part answers the question.

Comment: You can end up with an invalid `Range` by deleting cells - see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127311/vba-what-happens-to-range-objects-if-user-deletes-cells)

Comment: @barrowc thats a great link!

Comment: The problem behind was to have a User Defined Function returning a range collection. For example 'SUM(MyUDF(SOME_FILTER))'.
Now if the filter does not apply to any cell, what to return if not an empty collection?
Returning an invalid range complicates things further down the line, in this case the 'SUM' will be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

The correct representation of an empty range is Nothing.
For example:

```
Debug.Print Intersect(Range("A1"), Range("B1")) Is Nothing
True
```

So your function should return Nothing.
While there is such a thing as an empty collection, a Range cannot be an empty collection.