# Identify empty "Range" after it is deleted

Tags: excel, vba

I work with Ranges and sometimes all cells in a given object are deleted (`Range.Cells.Delete`)

I've played around and find these:

- after deleting all cells, type of the variable is still `Range` and it `Is Not Nothing`
- calling any of it's members results in Error "Object required"

Here is my small sub to test it:

```
Sub test()
    Dim r As Range

    Debug.Print r Is Nothing        ' -> true
    Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("a2")
    Debug.Print TypeName(r)         ' -> Range
    r.Cells.Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Debug.Print r Is Nothing        ' -> False
    Debug.Print TypeName(r)         ' -> Range
    Debug.Print r.Address           ' -> "Err: Object required"
    Debug.Print r.Cells.Count       ' -> "Err: Object required"

    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "Err: " & Err.Description
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

My question is: how can I determine (hopefully without error handling) whether an object is an empty `Range`?

Shortest option I've found so far:

```
Function IsEmptyRange(testRange As Range) As Boolean
    If TypeName(testRange) <> "Range" Then
        IsEmptyRange = False
    Else
        On Error GoTo EmptyRange
        IsEmptyRange = testRange.Cells.Count = 0
        If False Then
EmptyRange:
            Err.Clear
            IsEmptyRange = True
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: What is the idea of `If False Then`? Avoiding `Exit Function`? If this is really the case, then read this -> http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm and follow the practices.

Comment: The idea is to keep the logical flow of the code. I know placing error handlers at the end of the function, and generally I do so, however in cases like this (where I'd like to use `If`, but VBA doesn't allow me) I use this construct. It's easier to read (at least for me)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an interesting discussion about this on [Daily Dose of Excel](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2012/08/28/range-variables-and-deleted-cells/) pointing to a similar Stack Overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127311/vba-what-happens-to-range-objects-if-user-deletes-cells). The DDoE doesn't give a 'solution' but the discussion is illuminating regarding 'expected behaviour'. The SO post does (by @DougGlancy) but it is just a version of your code (perhaps slightly better because no `If False Then...` construct required).

IMO the best practice here is to remember to set your reference variables to `Nothing` if, and when, you can. E.g.

```
Sub test()
    Dim r As Range

    Debug.Print r Is Nothing        ' -> true
    Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("a2")
    Debug.Print TypeName(r)         ' -> Range
    r.Cells.Delete shift:=xlShiftUp

    Set r = Nothing                 ' -> end of problem

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Debug.Print r Is Nothing        ' -> True

    If Not r Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print TypeName(r)         ' -> Range
        Debug.Print r.Address           ' -> "Err: Object required"
        Debug.Print r.Cells.Count       ' -> "Err: Object required"
    End If

    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "Err: " & Err.Description
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

The tendency is probably to let scope deal with the clean-up (i.e. `r` will go out of scope once the `Sub` is complete) but it is better to do the clean-up yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. " set your reference variables to `Nothing`" - yes that would be great, however in my real code I delete parts row by row (`r.Rows(r.Rows.Count).Delete`) and checking always whether I've only one row remaining seems to be overkill (however just as I write it I'll may implement this method).

Comment: What If I had, for any reason, to return the address? Is it impossible to get it from the variable in this case?

Comment: All the properties are error 424 because the reference is invalid. So you can't return the address

Comment: But why is the reference invalid? I don't get it.
`Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("A2")` defines the reference for r (A range object pointing to "A2")
`Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Address` returns $A$2
`Debug.Print r.Address`, that should also return $A$2, gives an error

Comment: Reference = the bit of memory that represented `ActiveSheet.Range("A2")`. When the `Delete` happens a new bit of memory represents `ActiveSheet.Range("A2")` and `r` still points to the old bit of memory. This is what I mean by the 'reference is invalid'. That is why `r` is still a `Range` but all the properties return an error.

Comment: You see, I was so confused by "Why is the range here but it is not getting the reference" that I totally missed the deleted line. It makes sense now. Thanks!

Comment: I remember both those threads - on DDoE and the 'Stack - from five years go: some of the heavyweights the Excel world weighed in and the short answer is: `For` loops with a decrementing counter (not `For ...Each` loops!) are the way to go. And the underlying implementation is broken: your code **will** run into an error condition and an error-handler will be an intrinsic component, not an avoidable 'exception'.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I don't have any loop, therefore `For ... Step -1`, as Nigel Heffernan says, is not a solution.

With this problem the correct solution will depend on the context.
This is mine:

```
Sub test()
    'Mi context: from C2 all the cells are empty
    Dim Rng As Range
    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:B2")
    
    'trim all cells in Rng
    Rng = Application.Trim(Rng.Value)
    
    'I use CountIf instead xlCellTypeBlanks because it
    'would give an error if there are no empty cells
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, "") > 0 Then
        'delete all empty cells in Rng
        Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    End If
        
    'Assign Rng again
    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:B2")
    
    'and check again if all cells are empty
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, "") = Rng.Cells.Count Then
        MsgBox """A2:B2"" range have been deleted"
    Else
            
        'do something

    End If
End Sub
```

In other contexts you can store the initial values ​​of `Rng` and, after deleting cells in the range, compare with the newly assigned `Rng`